# iOS 9 UICollectionView horizontal reload data does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

NOTE: newbie in ios development.

I just created a collection view using vertical scrolling and it works when adding new cell(s) dynamically, but when I changed the scrolling to `horizontal` it does not work. I managed to fix it by reloading data on main thread.

My questions are:

1. Why I do not need to **explicitly** reload data on main thread when using vertical scrolling?
2. Is it best practice to reload data / reload specific cell or section data in `viewWillAppear`?

Anyone have experienced this issue? tested using XCode 7 iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s (all of them iOS9).

My code for reloading the data (for testing purposes) is in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  myViewModel.reload() // Reload the data with fresh data
  collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

In the other scene I display an Input and a button, when the button is pressed it will append a record to an array in memory (static)

```
@IBAction func create() {
  myViewModel.create(someInput.text!).persist() // Append to an array in memory (just for testing)
  navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, do you find how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

reloadData() must be executed in main thread:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```